# What are the most important things to ask a real estate agent before hiring them?

Tags: real-estate, home-ownership, first-time-home-buyer

I've been researching the best ways to search for a home, and questions have come up about real estate agents.  Getting a good real estate agent could potentially save you thousands of dollars, but I'm wondering how?  What do I need to ask a real estate agent when I am considering hiring them?  I found a real estate agent website that offers a free top ten list of questions to ask, but it of course requires a sign-up with information so the real estate agents can contact you.  What should I be looking out for?

Here is the list that I read about if looking to use an agent for **selling**:

> 1. What makes you different? Why should I list my home with you?
> 2. What is your company's track record and reputation in the market place?
> 3. What are your marketing plans for my home?
> 4. What has your company sold in my area?
> 5. Does your Broker control your advertising or do you?
> 6. On average, when your listings sell, how close is the selling price to the asking price?
> 7. On average, how long does it take for your listings to sell?
> 8. How many Buyers are you currently working with?
> 9. Do you have a reference list of clients I could contact?
> 10. What happens if I'm not happy with the job you are doing to get my home sold?

What would I need to ask a real estate agent if I'm considering using them for **buying** a home?  Or do I even need one for buying?

Comment: Your list of ten question is focused on selling a house, yet the rest of the question and the labels are focused on buying a home. The questions you want to ask in the two cases are different.

Comment: Obviously I got the wrong perspective here!  I am trying to buy a home, but i'm stabbing in the dark for what I need to talk to Agents about when I'm trying to Buy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an exhaustive list, but based on past experiences, I would ask:

- How are they paid, and by whom? This will usually be a standard percentage, paid by the seller, but best to go in eyes-open.
- What schedule do they prefer for showing houses? Week nights? Weekends?
- What neighborhoods are they familiar with and comfortable showing in?
- What pool of listings do they pull from? The MLS (Multiple Listing Service) or just their company's proprietary ones?
- If you find a listing on Craigslist or see a For Sale sign, will they represent you in that case? (Assuming you want them to)
- Do they have experience finding homes for people of your family size/income/expectations?
- Will they be exasperated if you are picky about houses, or want to haggle over price, or inspect/alter the contract? (if you care about these things)

I'm sure there's more, but these are details I've learned to look at.

Of course a big factor is trust, as Chuck Conway mentions. You may want to go with a friend for this reason. Or, you may want to go with someone else, to avoid frustrating a friend if you think the house hunt could run for a long time or be difficult. But either way, trust goes a long way.

Comment: *Closing costs are not always paid by the seller*. Traditionally, mortgage closing costs and buyer's agent fees are the responsibility of the buyer. However, it's the seller that's (hopefully) getting a big pile of cash from the home sale; many first-time homebuyers don't even have the 20% down. Given that, and in the current buyer's market, the seller is often expected to cover the buyer's costs. *That does not have to happen*; the seller is free to refuse any offer, even an advantageous one for them, for any reason at all.

Comment: "Do I like your personality?"

Answer (score 5):

I bought a home last year. The first thing for me was trust. I asked my friends and family for referrals. Second, was the connection. Did he or she understand my needs and what I am looking for.

In the end it worked out great. We found a home that was exactly what I wanted and where I wanted for 50k below market. The agent knew the property was a great deal and showed up with an offer ready to be signed in the advent we wanted to make an offer.

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question?

Answer (score -2):

You already have a great list of questions I would like to add these:

- Will I be working directly with you or with someone else in your office?
- What percentage of your clients are buyers? How many are sellers?
- How many homes have you closed in my neighborhood?
- Do you have a state license?

I prefer working with agents with a real estate license and that's what I would recommend for you as well. I once worked with a GREL licensed agent and he was super amazing.

Comment: To work with a agent they have to be licensed.  Your answer says nothing.  If you can improve it, the I will remove my down vote.